# Stop my Apple devices and PC desktop syncing Mozilla bookmarks

Tags: macos, ios, firefox, bookmarks

I have a MacBook Air and iPhone 7. I have a Dell desktop at work, and for some reason my Firefox bookmarks from my work PC are showing up on my Apple devices and I would like to remove them. At work I use Firefox, IE, and Chrome. On my Apple devices I use Safari and Chrome. I assume iCloud might be the problem here. I am wondering if (since I use it on all three devices, it is somehow syncing them. The shortcuts from my Firefox toolbar show up in my favorites on my Apple devices, and the bookmarks from my Firefox bookmark menu show up in my Safari bookmarks folder.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) In light of your comment (to my answer), could I suggest you [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/341690/edit) your question to provide these additional details and also to clarify what you're using on your work desktop and your personal devices? For example, at work do you only use Firefox, or do you also use Chrome? Do you use both Safari and Chrome on both your Mac and iPhone? And, are the bookmarks appearing in all browsers or...? If not all, which browsers on which devices?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! I'd actually like to know what's causing this so I can do it in _reverse_. (:

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about your Firefox bookmarks. If your bookmarks from work are showing up on your personal devices, then it's most likely because you're signed into your Firefox account on all your devices.

If you don't want to sync these devices with the same Firefox account, you should either create a different Firefox account for your personal devices, or not use a Firefox account at all for your personal devices.

For example:

- on your MacBook Air launch Firefox and go to **Firefox > Preferences > Firefox Account** to view your account settings.
- on your iPhone launch Firefox and go to Settings. At the very top you'll see your Firefox Account details.

Comment: That's what's most confusing to me! I don't use Firefox on any of my apple devices. I only use Safari and Chrome. Any idea what I would do in this case?